# Remove html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the content of html using JavaScript. Currently i am using jquery and  the code is `$('html').html('');`
But i don't want to use jquery. How can i remove the html content using JavasScript (not any other library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery:
`$("html").empty();`

JavaScript: `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = "";`

Comment: You can also just use `document.documentElement` instead of querying for the `html` tag.

Comment: @JasonSperske - It is a lightweight framework you know. Very fast.

Comment: @PeterOlson - documentElement can be different in versions of IE. Instead of querying a more supported approach would probably be `document.body.parentElement` which would yield the html element.

Comment: He just wanted to know how to delete the entire page. Getting what to delete isn't what he wanted here.

Comment: @JasonSperske - once I downloaded vanillaJS before reading the docs. The gzip size "killed" me xD

Answer (score 0):

See [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML).

```
element.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `html` element through `document.documentElement`.

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = "";
```

This is equivalent to `$("html").empty()` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `innerHTML` property.

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just use `innerHTML`

An example would look like:

```
 var id = document.getElementById("theID");
 id.innerHTML = "";
 // or by tags and go through all of them i.e
 var ids = document.getElementsByTagName("theID");
```